# Track 404 page in piwik 2.1.0 Update

Tags: matomo

in piwik FAQ part (http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_60/) there is a article about tracking 404 pages.

I have added the tracking code:

_paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', '404/URL = ' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.pathname+document.location.search) + '/From = ' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)]);

as mensioned in my piwik code bevor the line:

_paq.push(['trackPageView']);

The result is that also every valid URL is listed in the report: Actions > Pages Titles in the entry for 404 pages, i hope i explain it clear (english is not my language) an example a page or post who is ok is after putting the code also listed by 404 pages

do i have to edit something in the code?

hope somebody can help

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the tracking code **only** on error pages.